# Is there a way to disable the TraceHelper in SMO v16 nuget package?

Tags: c#, sql, nuget

It seems likes Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects v16 added a TraceHelper class, which I haven't seen before.  This seems to be adding some overhead for me and was curious if you could disable it.  I have decompiled a few of the assemblies and nothing stands out to me.  Any help with this would be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to completely stop the trace output:

```
Trace.Listeners.Clear();
```

Otherwise, the following post seems to be targetted to a specific library/assembly:

[Suppress Trace Messages From Specific DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353458/suppress-trace-messages-from-specific-dll/44128673)
(see answer from jrh)